# Allow pushing to a sublist of an object that the user doesn't have permission on in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm trying to create the following structure:

```
[
    {
        name: 'tester',
        comment: 'first comment',
        comments: [
            {
                name: 'tester2',
                comment: 'reply'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have the following security rules set up:

```
{
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        "comments": {
            "$recording": {
                "$comment": {
                    ".write": "!data.exists() && auth != null",
                    ".validate": "auth.name == newData.child('name').val() && newData.hasChildren(['name', 'comment']) && newData.child('comment').isString()",
                    "comments": {
                        "$reply": {
                            ".write": "!data.exists() && auth != null",
                            ".validate": "auth.name == newData.child('name').val() && newData.hasChildren(['name', 'comment']) && newData.child('comment').isString()"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to `push()` to the `comments` attribute of an existing comment, the `!data.exists()` in the first `.write` fails. Even if it wouldn't, the `auth.name == newData.child('name').val()` in the first `.validate` would fail.

So my question is: How can I selectively allow a push to an attribute while preventing changes to other attributes? In other words, can I somehow notice if I'm trying to write to /comments/1/2/3 in the `.write` or `.validate` for /comments/1/2?

Answer (score 1):

Write rules have an "OR" relationship. You only need one to succeed to allow the write. Validate rules have an "AND" relationship -- they all need to succeed to allow the write.

I'm not sure why your example above isn't working. You should be able to push to /comments/$recording/$comment/comments/

I would suggest running this through the Rules Simulator in your Firebase Dashboard to see why your write is failing.